# Prove that given two elements $a,b$ of relatively prime degree in a field extension $K$, $F(a) \cap F(b) = F$

Tags: proof-verification, ring-theory

**Problem**

Let $F$ be a field, and $K$ a field extension of $F$. Prove the following: Suppose $a,b \in K$ are algebraic over $F$ with degrees $m$ and $n$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. Then $F(a) \cap F(b) = F$.

**Attempt**

The equality $F(a) \cap F(b) = F$ implies that the only elements shared by $F(a)$ and $F(b)$ are contained within $F$ itself. $F(a)$ is the smallest field containing $F$ and $a$, and likewise with $F(b)$. Since the degrees of $a$ and $b$ over $F$ are relatively prime, <s>one cannot be expressed as a multiple of the other</s>. It follows that $b \not\in F(a)$ and $a \not\in F(b)$. Thus, $F(a) \cap F(b) = F$.

**Questions**

Does the fact that the degrees of $a$ and $b$ over $F$ are relatively prime imply that each is not contained in the field extension of the other? If not, what else am I missing?

Comment: Consider the degree $|F(a)\cap F(b):F|$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I think it would be 1, but I may just be using circular logic.

Comment: You've got to clean this up: $a$ and $b$ are not relatively prime, it's their degrees which are. Each is a multiple of the other.

Comment: You are still asserting "one can't be expressed as a multiple of the other". In a field $a=(ab^{-1})b$.

Comment: Nor have you fixed the final paragraph nor the title.

Comment: If it's the case that the degree of $[F(a) \cap F(b) : F] = 1$, then it would seem that it's not really an "extension" at all (since we're extending F to F). What am I missing that would imply that this degree would be 1?